# How to hide navigation portlet after logout?

Tags: plone

How to hide a navigation portlet after logging out? What I exactly want is, if a logged-in  admin visits a site, the navigation portlet should appear and be visible to him until he logs out from the plone site. But if a normal user visits the plone site, the portlet should not appear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A nice feature of Plone is the option to assign portlets not only to locations, but also to contenttypes and groups. To solve your request, simply assign the portlet to the group 'Administrators'.

To do that, go to your Plonesite's controlpanel, click 'Users and Groups', click on green tab 'Groups', click on 'Administrators', click on the tab 'Group portlets', add a portlet.

To reproduce this programtically, use Genericsetup (export portlets.xml of the site and include the relevant parts in your product).

For completeness: Similiar for assigning portlets to a contenttype, you go to the controlpanel, click 'Types', choose the wanted type (f.e. 'Event') of the dropdownlist and click on 'Manage portlets assigned to this content type', assign portlet. Progragramtically reproducable via exporting 'Types' and including it to your products.

Comment: @@Ida : Hi , can you please tell me the exact steps to hide the navigation portlet after logout. I tried many ways but nothing helps me. So please tell me clearly what to do.

Comment: @NirmalaSudhir: Updated answer, HTH.

Comment: @@ida: Hi, the answer  you provided me for my issue is not working. I did evrything as you said

Comment: What exactly isn't working? BTW: @@ida will not work, to inform me, syntax is `@exactUsername`.

Comment: :You said that use controlpanel->users and groups to hide the navigation portlet when logged out. i followed the steps you told me but its not working. Still i see the navigation portlet when logged out

Comment: I didn't say "use controlpanel->users and groups to hide the navigation portlet when logged out", I wrote *assign* a portlet to Administrators. Please reread and follow he steps carefully, this works for sure, it's OOTB-behaviour.

Comment: :You said  this "A nice feature of Plone is the option to assign portlets not only to locations, but also to contenttypes and groups. To solve your request, simply assign the portlet to the group 'Administrators'.
To do that, go to your Plonesite's controlpanel, click 'Users and Groups', click on green tab 'Groups', click on 'Administrators', click on the tab 'Group portlets', add a portlet."... And i followed the same.

Comment: @NirmalaSudhir Did you also REMOVE the default navigation portlet?

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Thanks for stepping in, I really don't know how to explain better a rather easy UI-click-task.

Comment: @NirmalaSudhir: Do you log in as site-admin or as ZOPE-admin?

Comment: Addition: The ZOPE-Admin doesn't belong to the Administrators-group of a Plonesite, thus the portlet-behaviour wouldn't apply in that case, you'd need to act as a site-Administrator to see the effect (and generally avoid acting as ZOPE-admin, unless for special reasons like creating a new site).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,  for all the  response towards my question. Unfortunately the solution you all provided doesn't work for me. So I myself Did like this to hide a navigation portlet when  logged out.

Step 1: In overrides.zcml

```
<plone:portlet
    name="navigation_bar"
    interface="plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation.INavigationPortlet"
    assignment="plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation.Assignment"
    renderer=".browser.navi_portlet.navigation_portlet"
    addview="plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation.AddForm"
    editview="plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation.EditForm"
    />

<plone:portletRenderer
     portlet="plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation.INavigationPortlet"
     class=".browser.navi_portlet.navigation_portlet"
     layer=".interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
     />
```

renderer=".browser.navi_portlet.navigation_portlet" here browser is my folder which contains a file called navi_portlet with a method navigation_portlet.

step 2: navi_portlet.py:

```
 from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView
 from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile
 from Products.CMFPlone import PloneMessageFactory as _
 from plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation import Renderer
 from plone.app.layout.viewlets.common import PersonalBarViewlet
 from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile
 from plone.app.layout.globals.interfaces import IViewView

 class navigation_portlet(Renderer,PersonalBarViewlet):

    _template= ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/nav_portlet.pt')

    def nav_up(self):
        mytal = PersonalBarViewlet.update(self)
```

what i did in navi_portlet.py is i just inherited the  PersonalBarViewlet from viewlets(eggs folder) and Renderer from portlets(eggs folder). To override the default behavior to hide it when logged out.

step 3:  nav_portlet.pt

```
   <dl   class="actionMenu deactivated"  id="portlet portletNavigationTree"
   tal:define="user_actions python:view.nav_up();root view/navigation_root"
   tal:condition="python:view.user_actions and not view.anonymous">
   <tal:block condition="not: view/anonymous">
   <dt class="portletHeader"
    tal:attributes="class python:view.hasName() and 'portletHeader' or 'portletHeader hiddenStructure'">
    <span class="portletTopLeft"></span>

    <a href="#"
       class="tile"
       tal:attributes="href string:${view/heading_link_target}"
       tal:content="view/title"
       i18n:translate="">Navigation</a>
    <span class="portletTopRight"></span>
</dt>

<dd class="portletItem lastItem">
    <ul class="navTree navTreeLevel0">
        <li tal:define="selectedClass view/root_item_class;
                        li_class python:selectedClass and ' navTreeCurrentNode' or '';
                        normalizeString nocall:context/plone_utils/normalizeString;
                        section_title root/Title;
                        section python:normalizeString(section_title);"
            tal:condition="view/include_top"
            tal:attributes="class string:navTreeItem navTreeTopNode${li_class} section-${section}">
            <div tal:define="rootIsPortal view/root_is_portal;
                             root_icon view/root_icon;
                             root_type root/portal_type;
                             root_type_class python:'contenttype-' + normalizeString(root_type);
                             root_class python:rootIsPortal and 'contenttype-plone-site' or root_type_class;">
               <a tal:attributes="href root/absolute_url;
                                  title root/Description;
                                  class python:' '.join([root_class, selectedClass]).strip();">



               <img tal:replace="structure root_icon/html_tag" tal:condition="not:rootIsPortal" />
               <span tal:omit-tag=""
                     tal:condition="rootIsPortal"
                     i18n:translate="tabs_home">Home</span>
               <span tal:condition="not:rootIsPortal"
                     tal:replace="root/Title">Root item title</span>
               </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li tal:replace="structure view/createNavTree">
            SUBTREE
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span class="portletBottomLeft"></span>
    <span class="portletBottomRight"></span>
</dd>
```

What i tried to do in nav_portlet.pt is to merge both portlets(Navigation Portlet using Render(class)) and viewlets(PersonalBarViewlet). so that i used the user_action method from the PersonalBarViewlet Class (i.etal:condition="python:view.user_actions and not view.anonymous">) to hide the Navigation Portlet when logged out.

Hope You all get my points and what i did.

Thanks

Comment: You could have saved a lot of work, if you could have described at which point exactly what didn't work. This solution is an unnessary overbloat for the task, which is already built-in, OOTB, clickable, Plone-stack-behaviour. BTW: Your solution distincts whether the user is logged-in or not, but not, if s/he is an admin and the other condition looks, if the personal-bar is present, which you probably don't need here and can become an obstacle when you use your portlet in another context.